# ElasticSearch compare all documents from 2 indices

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-cloud

I have 2 indices: submissions and restored-submissions.

`submissions` is our production index and `restored-submissions` is an index created from a snapshot.
I would like to compare both indices and find any differences in documents, for example, new documents or updated documents. Is there a way of doing that in ElasticSearch?